# Python - Overwrite data in a text box

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a countdown timer in a gui in tkinter.

```
def verboseSleep(seconds):
chars = len(str(seconds))
s = "{:" + str(chars) + "d}s"
int = cntdn = seconds + 1
for i in range(seconds, 0, -1):
    sys.stdout.write(str("\b" * (chars+1)) + s.format(i))
    
    cntdn = cntdn - 1
    msg_seconds = str(cntdn)
    outText.insert(tk.END, msg_seconds) # insert countdown in text box here
    window.update_idletasks()
    
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
sys.stdout.write(str("\b" * (chars + 1)))   # Remove all evidence of our countdown timer.
sys.stdout.flush()
```

At the moment my output looks like this:

[image: Current Output]

I'm counting down from 90, as you can see it just appends the results to the end making a long gibberish number.  I need to either erase that line and print the new number in the beginning, or carriage return to the left and overwrite the previous text.  How do I do this?

**UPDATE**

```
outText = Text(window, width=50, height=20, wrap=WORD)
outText.grid(row=8, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
```

Comment: The `delete` method is documented. Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

first of all delete existing text in `outText` and then insert new one:

```
outText.delete(0, "end")
outText.insert(tk.END, msg_seconds)
```

**UPDATE:**
if you want to remove just last line from the entry:

```
#get text from entry
txt = outText.get()
#remove text from entry
outText.delete(0, "end")
#split as lines
lines = txt.splitlines()
#remove last line
lines = lines[:-1]
#join as string
txt = '\n'.join(lines)
#put back in the entry
outText.insert(tk.END, txt)
```

Comment: It worked too well!  1 things.  

1.)  I just need to delete the current line?  if I put  
    outText.delete(0.0, "end")  

then it deletes everything from 0.0 (beginning) to the end.  I have other stuff above the current line that I'd like to retain.  How do I specify the current line when the current line is a variable?

Comment: so you want to retain only first line?

Comment: @nearbyatom: `0.0` is not the first character, `"1.0"` is.

Comment: @godot - Unfortunately the number of lines I need to retain can vary.  That's why I can only delete the last line.

Comment: @godot - Sorry but what are arguments for get()?  The compiler says get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'

Comment: @godot - outText is the text box where the output (such as the countdown timer) will be displayed.

Comment: @godot - I updated the post with the definition of outText.  Take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to extract all of the data, remove some, and then insert it back. The `delete` method can easily remove a single line.

Comment: @BryanOakley - But how do I write the delete argument to delete only the last line?  If the last line was always on the same line I can see it happening.  But the last line I want to delete isn't always the same line.  Sometimes line 6, sometimes 10, etc.

Comment: @nearbyatom: you can use expressions for indexes. For example `"end-1c linestart"` refers to the start of the last line before the automatic trailing newline. See the "expressions" section here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm